# Can Jenkins send an artifact created by a build to the user that triggered the build?

Tags: jenkins, devops

I am setting up a build for a project in jenkins that will output an artifact once the build is completed. This artifact is used to perform tests on a device, so the goal is to have the user receive the artifact as quickly as the build is completed.

Is there a way for jenkins to know which user pushed the changes to bitbucket that triggered the build so that it can then send the artifact via email or slack?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you doing with the artifact after it built? in case it is stored on an artifact repository you can send the url for downloading the artifact after it successfully uploads it.

Comment: So the artifact will be published in the jenkins project. Jenkins can can send the artifact via slack or email. I guess there will need to be another script for to check who was the latest to change the bitbucket repo and have it send the artifact to that user.

Comment: don't you store the artifact in some artifact repository to manage versions or artifacts ?

Comment: Not at the moment, but say that we did store it somewhere. Is there a way to notify the interested user that the build has completed and point him the artifact that was just created? Thanks @MickeyHovel.

Comment: In case you do so you can share at the end of the build the link to the artifact repo where the user can directly download it. and this is the desired approach instead of attaching a binary file to an email in every build